# Meaning of $\int d^2T$

Tags: integration, derivatives

I was thinking about higher derivatives and was wondering if there is any meaning mathematically behind:
$$\int d^2T$$
where $T$ is a variable or a function, I don't think it matters. If we let $T=f(t)$ then we would get:
$$\frac{d^2T}{dt^2}=\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{dT}{dt}\right]$$
However I have still not found anything about if this exists, what it would represent?

Thanks in advance, sorry if this question is vague or unclear

Comment: You still haven't told us what the integral would represent in your case. The problem with this is, that unlike the case of the first derivative, where the chain rule saves you, this expression can't be defined *unless* you know the *independent* variable to start with. In other words, if I instead write $T=g(s)$, then you'll get a totally different answer for $\int d^2 T$, once you define it :P

Comment: Probably not, but we could add a meaning to $\int f d^2t$ of 'double anti-derivative', as in the function $F$ such that $F'' = f$, such function of course would be unique up to linear function. In general we could add a meaning to $\int f d^nt$ as the $n$-th anti-derivative, that is the function for which $F^{(n)} = f$, and it would be unique up to a polynomial of degree $n-1$

Comment: I have no particular usage for this, but since we are able to think of integrals of e.g. $dx$ as Riemann sums and visual them as the summation of area, I meant does anything along those lines exist for this

Comment: Let's be careless. If $T(t)$ is twice differentiable then $d^2 T(t) = T''(t) dt^2$. Hence we ought to have
$$
\int d^2T(t) = \int T''(t)dt^2.
$$
Now, I would interpret $dt^2$ as quadrating variation, in the same sense that $(dW_t)^2 = dt$ when $W$ is a Brownian motion. Mimicking a result from stochastic calculus where the quadratic variation is the limit of 'quadratic sums', we may define $\int f(t) dt^2$ as the limit of partial sums $\sum_i f(\xi_i)(\Delta x_i)^2$ as the mesh (or quadratic mesh?) of the partition $\{x_i\}_i$ goes to zero. I don't know if any of this actually makes sense.

Comment: @Sisyphus thats great yeah, was looking for a use case just like this